# need to fetch record of last one id

Tags: mysql

I have a table in this structure but need to get record of only every last qst_id everytime like here I need to get record of qst_id=1 means need to get ans_id=35 but how I can use query.I am doing this because I have to update email for every last survey.

```
     ans_id qst_id  opt
        25      1   option1
        26      2   option1
        27      3   option2
        28      4   option2
        29      5   option2
        30      6   option2
        31      7   option2
        32      8   option2
        33      9   option2
        34      10  option2
        35      1   option1
        36      2   option1
        37      3   option1
        38      4   option1
        39      5   option1
        40      6   option1
        41      7   option1
        42      8   option1
        43      9   option1
        44      10  option1
```

Comment: please add complete sample output also, it will help you SO users to answer you easily.

Answer (score 0):

In **MySQL 5.x** you can use a table expression, as in:

```
select t.*
from t
join (
  select qst_id, max(ans_id) as max_ans_id
  from t
  group by qst_id
) x on x.qst_id = t.qst_id and x.max_ans_id = t.ans_id
```

In **MySQL 8.x** you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to find the last row for each `qst_id`, as in:

```
select ans_id, qst_id, opt
from (
  select 
    ans_id, qst_id, opt,
    row_number() over(partition by qst_id 
                      order by ans_id desc) as rn
  from t
) x
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the values of `ans_id` will be Auto Increment, then use `order by` with `limit`

```
select qst_id from your_table order by ans_id desc limit 1;
```